# Can't access web content, swift (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

So, I'm just starting to learn **Swift**, and I was trying to do this simple app that prints by console the content of a web page. This code is the same code from a video, and it works fine in it. For some reason, I don't get any output, I'm not getting the content from the web page. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to access the web content? Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
            println(String(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!))
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the NSURLSession object could be released before the response.
You can declare the NSURLSession object out of viewDidLoad, I mean you should make the NSURLSession object a property of this viewController. Just try.

Comment: I tried that, I tried doing another code where when I press a button it should display the web content, but it doesn't, it's like it never gets it.